# Word to mean hating/disliking a particular country?

Tags: single-word-requests

So my friend and I were making jokes about a particular country, and then when attempting to describe the behavior, we realized there was no word for it. Racist is not the correct term because countries can have many different kinds of citizens. Also, we were making fun of the place, not the people that lived there. Nationalist is also not the correct term because that implies a particular fervor for one's own country, but not necessarily a distaste for another one.

In summary, is there a word in the english language that describe a disdain for a particular geographic region/country? The closest thing I could come up with was too specific, like "Anti-American", but nothing that could be applied to a general place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Xenophobic](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/xenophobia)

> fear or hatred of foreigners, people from different cultures, or strangers

In this case, you could say that you were being *xenophobic* towards a specific country.

Comment: -phile and -phobe suffixes are used - francophile, russophobe.